# UITextField position is different on iPhone 5 versus older iPhone (3GS/4/4S)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a UITextbox on the bottom of my screen (which is the table you see in the graphic below).

On the iPhone 3GS/4/4S it shows up correctly on the bottom.  However, on my iphone 5, it is on the same screen where it would normally be on a regular iphone, screenshot below:

[image: iphone 5 retina display]

Is there a way to resolve this through IB or must it be done with code?
You can see a bit of blank white space at the bottom where the last tab is cut off, it looks like its still reserving room for the input box.

Comment: you can fix this either in IB or in code; are you using strings and struts (i.e. are you supporting iOS 5) or are you using AutoLayout (which is iOS 6 & newer)?  also, what exactly *is* wrong with how it looks? is it just that the UITextView is cut off a bit?

Comment: I am supporting iOS5 and not using AutoLayout.  The input box is supposed to be directly above the TabBar at the bottom.  You can see a bit of blank white space at the bottom where the table is not outputting text, its where the box should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In interface builder (where you're using strings & struts and ***NOT*** auto layout), you can change what you're looking at by selecting the view controller you want to work with and then, in the Attributes Inspector for the view controller, touch this pop-up menu:

iPhone 5 screen size:

[image]

iPhone 4 & earlier screen size:

[image: iPhone 4S & earlier screen sizes]

You can then see the difference between the two iPhone screen sizes.

Now, to get the text field to hug (or stay aligned at the bottom), click the bottom strut for the text field.  It should look something like this:

[image: I think this is a strut, not a spring]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough - saved these images for future reference.  For future uses...what do you recommend to use for IB?  Mine was set on "Inferred" and im still not sure what is best to use in the future.

Comment: In the future, I'm going to try to stick with Auto Layout (which is what I'm trying to use for my iOS 6 & newer projects, depending on how flexible my clients are), but in general yes... "inferred" is okay. It's just for hair splitters like the problem of what you ran into, which is when we need to look at the the simulated 3.5 & 4 inch tall screens.